# How to get specific field from model?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

How to change following model request to get only specific fields?

```
Event::whereIn("idEvent", $this->ids)->get();
```

I tried:

```
Event::select(["name", "id"])->whereIn("idEvent", $this->ids)->get();
```

Comment: `->get()` produces a `Collection`, or an enhanced array of `Event` models. Are you looping them? Show your full code please; none of the code above shows an attempt at accessing a specific field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try

```
Event::whereIn("idEvent", $this->ids)->pluck(["id", "name"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the below:

```
Event::whereIn("idEvent", $this->ids)->get(['name', 'id']);
```

Answer (score -1):

Event::where("idEvent", $this->ids)->select('name', 'id')->get();
You can use select to choose specific model attributes (columns in DB for that model).

The above would select the name and id where Event models, idEvent is $this->ids.

Comment: I don't know why you deducted me this works perfectly.  I suggest looking at your models/code but I suggest reading the docs.  Here you go: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#selects .   According to your question and the laravel docs this should work just fine.

Comment: They didn't, I did. There is no difference between `select(["name", "id"])` and `select('name', 'id')`, so no, this doesn't actually answer the question. The question can't be answered in it's current state, as there isn't a clear question to answer... They don't say why this doesn't work, so you're guessing.

Comment: So sorry Mr. Lewis for trying to help out.  Maybe one day I'll wake up a Sr. Level developer and never make a mistake.

Comment: What makes you think I'm a Sr. developer? Trying to help out is fine, and appreciated, but it it's wrong, you're gonna get a downvote. I've posted tons of mistakes and gotten _tons_ of downvotes; that's just how Stackoverflow works.

Comment: I guess I'd figure you'd downvote the initial question since according to you in it's current state cannot be answered.  I promise though that is how you'd select but I'm sure you know that.  Anyways I'll just delete my answer, sorry to interrupt you from whatever important stuff it is that you have to do.